# How to find the inverse of this particular symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Basically, I have a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, which looks like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \cdots & \alpha \\
\alpha & 1 & \cdots &\alpha \\
\vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\alpha & \cdots & \alpha & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to know is there a general formula  / solution for solving the inverse of this matrix for $n = 1,2,3,4,5,6......$

Comment: How about if you carefully do 1 by 1, then 2 by 2, then 3 by 3, and if you still don't know, get back to us.

Comment: I assume $\alpha\neq 1$, right?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the matrix are $\lambda_1=1+(n-1)\alpha$ and $\lambda_2=\cdots=\lambda_n=1-\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $J$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of ones, then you want to find $B$ such that
$$
\alpha BJ + (1-  \alpha) B = I \tag{1}
$$
Since $J^2 = nJ$, this implies
$$
n \alpha B J + (1 - \alpha) B J = J
$$
Therefore we must assume $1 + (n-1)\alpha \ne 0$, and
$$
BJ = \frac{1}{1 + (n-1)\alpha} J
$$
Plugging this back into (1),
$$
\frac{\alpha}{1 + (n-1)\alpha} J + (1-  \alpha) B = I
$$
Now solve for $B$.